# Is it possible to map routes /users/:id and /users/me into single controller in Plumier

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, plumier

I have a controller to handle `/users` route for each methods (`GET`, `POST`, `PUT`, `DELETE`) like below (method body removed). Its mostly like the code from example [here](https://plumierjs.com/docs/tutorials/basic-sql/create-restful-api#user-controller)

```js
export class UsersController {
    @route.get("")
    all(@val.optional() offset: number, @val.optional() limit: number) { }

    @route.get(":id")
    get(@val.mongoId() id: string) { }

    @route.post("")
    async save(data: User) { }

    @route.put(":id")
    async update(@val.mongoId() id: string, data: User) { }

    @route.delete(":id")
    delete(@val.mongoId() id: string) { }
}
```

Above controller will handles:

```
GET    /users?offest&limit
POST   /users
GET    /users/:id
PUT    /users/:id
DELETE /users/:id
```

I also create another shorthand endpoint for current login user with endpoints below:

```
GET    /users/me
PUT    /users/me
DELETE /users/me
```

From the documentation [here](https://plumierjs.com/docs/refs/route#multiple-route-decorator), saying that a controller / action can be decorated using multiple route decorators. **I wonder if there is a way to "reuse" above controller to handle current login user endpoints above**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes its possible, Plumier provide a very flexible route setup make it possible to solve the issue.

You need to move the three methods for `/users/:id` into separate controller so it will be possible to make the same route pattern like below:

```js
@route.root("/users/me")
@route.root("/users/:id")
@middleware.use({
    execute: async i => {
        if (i.context.path.search(/users\/me$/i))
            i.context.parameters![0] = i.context.state.user.userId
        return i.proceed()
    }
})
export class UserByIdController {
    @route.get("")
    get(@val.optional() @val.mongoId() id: string) {}

    @route.put("")
    update(@val.optional() @val.mongoId() id: string, data: User) {}

    @route.delete("")
    delete(@val.optional() @val.mongoId() id: string) {}
}
```

By using above setup the new controller will generated into 6 routes like expected:

```
GET    /users/me
PUT    /users/me
DELETE /users/me
GET    /users/:id
PUT    /users/:id
DELETE /users/:id
```

Keep in mind that now the `id` parameter of all contained methods need to be optional to handle `/users/me`, thats why we add `@val.optional()` on the parameter.

The most important thing is we apply a controller specific middleware and do meta programming to populate the first method parameter (the `id` parameter) with current user id.

```js
if (i.context.path.search(/users\/me$/i))
   i.context.parameters![0] = i.context.state.user.userId
return i.proceed()
```

Above snippet means we check if the current path of the request ends with `users/me` then assigned the first parameter of the current action with current login user id. By doing this we done some modification without affecting the current logic inside the method body.

**important:** order position of the route decorator `@route.root("/users/me")` is important, it should be on the top of `/users/:id`.

Answer (score 0):

Start from version 1.0.0-rc.0 Plumier uses better [application lifecycle](https://plumierjs.com/docs/extend#application-lifecycle). Thus its now possible to access `ctx.state.user` from inside custom binder. Its now the code even look cleaner.

```js
import { route, CustomBinderFunction as Bind, bind } from "plumier"

const bindUserId: Bind = ctx => ctx.path.match(/me/i) ? ctx.state.user.userId : ctx.query.id


export class UsersController {
    @route.get("")
    all(@val.optional() offset: number, @val.optional() limit: number) { }

    @route.get("me")
    @route.get(":id")
    get(@val.mongoId() @bind.custom(bindUserId) id: string) { }

    @route.get("me")
    @route.post("")
    async save(data: User) { }

    @route.get("me")
    @route.put(":id")
    async update(@val.mongoId()  @bind.custom(bindUserId) id: string, data: User) { }

    @route.get("me")
    @route.delete(":id")
    delete(@val.mongoId() @bind.custom(bindUserId) id: string) { }
}
```

Now the code look more straight forward.. We bind the `id` parameter by checking if the current request path contains `me` then return current login user id, else return from the query parameter.

Note that you can combine decorator using `mergeDecorator` from `tinspector`, to combine the duplicate `@val.mongoid() @bind.custom(bindUserId)`.

```js
import { mergeDecorator } from "tinspector"

function bindUserId() {
    return mergeDecorator(
        bind.custom(ctx => ctx.path.match(/me/i) ? ctx.state.user.userId : ctx.query.id),
        val.mongoId()
    )
}
```

Then simply use it like below :

```js
export class UsersController {

    @route.get("me")
    @route.get(":id")
    get(@bindUserId() id: string) { }
}
```